# Postgres - Filtering out words but excluding another pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I'm trying to extract rows that has `like '%asian%'`. But the issue I'm having is this includes `caucasian`.

Could someone help me with a pattern that includes any `label like '%asian%'` but excludes `caucasian`? I'm mainly looking for an elegant solution. I already have a solution where I have a temp table that includes `'%asian%'` in the result set, and then I delete any results with `caucasian`. It's not elegant so I'm looking for a simpler solution to this.

Here is an example of the result set:

```
label
--------------------
WHITE/CAUCASIAN
Asian/Pacif Isl His
CAUCASIAN
ASIAN
```

And I would like the result to be

```
label
--------------------
Asian/Pacif Isl His
ASIAN
```

Comment: `WHERE label like '%asian%' and label <> 'caucasian'` ? Or please give more explicite exemple!

Comment: I edited for clearer examples

Comment: and what you want to have as a result?

Comment: Ah man I'm so sorry for not being clear. Edited again.

Comment: `WHERE label ilike '%asian%' and label not ilike '%caucasian%' ` ?

Comment: Dang I didn't think it was that easy! Thanks that worked. If you can put it as an answer I'll mark it as approved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 WHERE label ilike '%asian%' and label not ilike '%caucasian%' ?
```

[source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could try full-text search, but postgres's parser will treat a/b as a file path, so won't help in this case.

Houari's answer is fine but will be slow on big tables.

Try this:

```
--your table:

create table a (
  label text primary key
);

insert into a values 
('WHITE/CAUCASIAN'),
('Asian/Pacif Isl His'),
('CAUCASIAN'),
('ASIAN');

--a function to split your labels into text arrays (splits on forward slash or space):

create or replace function get_terms(text) returns text[] language sql as '
  select regexp_split_to_array(lower($1), ''[\/ ]'');
'

--create a functional index for fast lookup:
create index terms on a using gin (get_terms(label));

--find rows where there is an array overlap:
select * from a where get_terms(label) && array['asian'];
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/14407/8

Comment: This is actually not a bad implementation. It will be useful for when I try to extract other races. Thank you.